# Who was E. Midy, the eponym of Midy's Theorem?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

I have just become aware of the 19th century French mathematician **E. Midy**, who apparently was the first to prove what is now known as **Midy's theorem**.

I can find out nothing about this mathematician beyond the fact that he wrote a paper *De Quelques Propriétés des Nombres et des Fractions Décimales Périodiques* from which "Midy's theorem" seems to have come.

Does anyone have any access to more information about him? Full name, dates and places of birth and death help to put him into context, but any other relevant details more than welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the entry for Etienne Midy on [Biographies of Scientists - Numericana](http://www.numericana.com/fame/bio.htm#midy):

> ### Etienne Midy   (c. 1775,  fl. 1846)
>
> <sup>[Midy's theorem](http://www.numericana.com/answer/numeration.htm#midy) (1835)</sup>
>
> His name is spelled  *Meidy*  in some records.  He was probably already teaching when  *Napoléon*  instituted the  *lycées*,  in 1802.  Midy himself advertised he had taught  *mathématiques spéciales*  at [Cahors](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyc%C3%A9e_Gambetta_(Cahors)) (1821-1826) and [Orléans](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyc%C3%A9e_Pothier) (1826-1832) before moving to Nantes.
>
> At the  *Collège Royal de Nantes*  (future  [Lycée Clémenceau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyc%C3%A9e_Georges_Clemenceau_(Nantes)))  Midy taught  *mathématiques élémentaires*  from 1833 to 1837.  That post was entrusted to a young  *normalien*  (Alexandre Lepord, ENS 1834)  when Midy was promoted to teach  *mathématiques spéciales*  again in 1837-1838  (after M. Dorveau resigned).  Midy would be replaced in this capacity by M. Gascheau  (previously, professor of physics)  when a ministerial decree  (1838-11-17)  allowed him to retire.
>
> In Nantes,  Etienne Midy lived  *3, rue Richebourg,*  next to his workplace.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to assume the spelling Étienne Midy (with the accent) as (having googled and got a load more results) I see a fair few results with the accent included, and a) the Étienne form does seem to be a solid standard, b) I understand that when capitalised, it is commonplace to omit the accent. Thoughts?

Comment: @PrimeMover The self-published pamphlet: E. Midy, *De quelques propriétés des nombres et des fractions décimales périodiques,* Nantes 1836, 21 pp., can be perused at [TIB](https://www.tib.eu/en/) as a high-quality [scan](https://goobi.tib.eu/viewer/image/1014596483/1/#topDocAnchor)

Comment: Other publications: Midy (Étienne), "Analyse indéterminée du premier degré," *Nouvelles annales de mathématiques*, Vol. 4 (1845), pp. 146-152 ([Google scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nouvelles_annales_de_mathematiques_journ/X-A_na1XJ_MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=146));
Midy (Étienne),"Equations polaires," *Nouvelles annales de mathématiques*, Vol. 4 (1845), pp. 597-606 ([Google scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nouvelles_annales_de_mathematiques_journ/X-A_na1XJ_MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=597))

Comment: Another pamphlet: E. Midy, *Du théorème de M. Sturm, èt de ses applications numériques,* Nantes 1836, 37 pp. & 2 tables ([scan at BNF Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6485063f.texteImage))

Comment: Possibly the same author: Midy, "Sur une proprieté des nombres," *Nouvelles annales de mathématiques*, Vol. 5 (1846), pp. 640-646 ([Google scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nouvelles_annales_de_math%C3%A9matiques/c8YLAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=640))

Comment: If the 1846 paper is by Etienne Midy, the author information states he was an instructor at Grande Sauve near Bordeaux at the time of publication. From the scant information I can find, Grande Sauve is the site of a former abbey that housed a teachers college at that time.

Comment: @njuffa Superb job as ever -- incidentally I found the "Nouvelles annales" website in the wake of this answer. It gives a full contents list, and all 15 of Midy's articles published between 1842 and 1846 can be found.

Comment: @PrimeMover There is a [court case](https://books.google.com/books?id=KMIoAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA149&ots=f2zfeYMpl4&pg=PA149) from 1856 involving one Jean-Baptiste Midy, son of one Etienne Midy, about the notarized gift of a house from father to son on March 4, 1853, stipulating donor may reside in said house until their death. The tax authorities were of the opinion this was actually a sale of real estate, rather than a gift (at lower tax rate). The house is in Fays-Billot (seems to be actually Fayl-Billot, a village in Haute-Marne). Whether this involved Etienne Midy the mathematician I cannot tell

Comment: @PrimeMover Non-math publication: E. Midy, *Sténographie nouvelle*, Paris 1839, 23 pp. & 1 plate ([Google scan](https://books.google.com/books?id=5PDSSASWlBsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)) Author identified as "Professeur émérite de l'Université, ancien professeur de mathématiques spéciales des colléges royaux d'Orleans et de Nantes."

Comment: @njuffa All excellent information. (Now I'm wondering why my question has invited a downvote.)